# wxmaxima assertion failed error

Tags: software-installation

Trying to install wxmaxima on a fresh installation of 14.04. maxima is installed successfully from the repository. I follow the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/wxMaxima), section II: Compiling Your Own WxMaxima Package. Downloaded wxMaxima-13.04.02.tar.gz from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxmaxima/files/)

I get no errors during installation. When trying to run wxmaxima, I get an `assertion failed` error. Full error traceback:

```
    ASSERT INFO:
    ../src/common/menucmn.cpp(982): assert "item" failed in Enable(): attempt to enable an item which doesn't exist

    BACKTRACE:
    [1] wxMenuBarBase::Enable(int, bool)
    [2] wxImageHandler::~wxImageHandler()
    [3] wxAppConsoleBase::CallEventHandler(wxEvtHandler*, wxEventFunctor&, wxEvent&) const
    [4] wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventIfMatchesId(wxEventTableEntryBase const&, wxEvtHandler*, wxEvent&)
    [5] wxEventHashTable::HandleEvent(wxEvent&, wxEvtHandler*)
    [6] wxEvtHandler::TryHereOnly(wxEvent&)
    [7] wxEvtHandler::DoTryChain(wxEvent&)
    [8] wxEvtHandler::ProcessEvent(wxEvent&)
    [9] wxMenuBase::UpdateUI(wxEvtHandler*)
    [10] wxMenuBarBase::UpdateMenus()
    [11] wxTopLevelWindowGTK::OnInternalIdle()
    [12] wxFrameBase::OnInternalIdle()
    [13] wxWindowBase::SendIdleEvents(wxIdleEvent&)
    [14] wxFrame::SendIdleEvents(wxIdleEvent&)
    [15] wxAppBase::ProcessIdle()
    [16] wxApp::DoIdle()
    [17] g_main_context_dispatch
    [18] g_main_loop_run
    [19] gtk_main
    [20] wxGUIEventLoop::DoRun()
    [21] wxEventLoopBase::Run()
    [22] wxAppTraits::RunLoopUntilChildExit(wxExecuteData&, wxEventLoopBase&)
    [23] wxGUIAppTraits::WaitForChild(wxExecuteData&)
    [24] wxExecute(char**, int, wxProcess*, wxExecuteEnv const*)
    [25] wxExecute(wxString const&, int, wxProcess*, wxExecuteEnv const*)
    [26] wxImageHandler::~wxImageHandler()
    [27] wxImageHandler::~wxImageHandler()
    [28] wxImageHandler::~wxImageHandler()
    [29] wxImageHandler::~wxImageHandler()
    [30] wxAppConsoleBase::CallEventHandler(wxEvtHandler*, wxEventFunctor&, wxEvent&) const
    [31] wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventIfMatchesId(wxEventTableEntryBase const&, wxEvtHandler*, wxEvent&)
    [32] wxEventHashTable::HandleEvent(wxEvent&, wxEvtHandler*)
    [33] wxEvtHandler::TryHereOnly(wxEvent&)
    [34] wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventLocally(wxEvent&)
    [35] wxEvtHandler::ProcessEvent(wxEvent&)
    [36] wxEvtHandler::ProcessPendingEvents()
    [37] wxAppConsoleBase::ProcessPendingEvents()
    [38] wxApp::DoIdle()
    [39] g_main_context_dispatch
    [40] g_main_loop_run
    [41] gtk_main
    [42] wxGUIEventLoop::DoRun()
    [43] wxEventLoopBase::Run()
    [44] wxDialog::ShowModal()
    [45] wxShowTip(wxWindow*, wxTipProvider*, bool)
    [46] wxImageHandler::~wxImageHandler()
    [47] wxFormatString::~wxFormatString()
    [48] wxFormatString::~wxFormatString()
    [49] wxEntry(int&, wchar_t**)
    [50] __libc_start_main
```

Any ideas what could have gone wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: That seems like a bug. You may report it. On the other side, why aren't you using the Ubuntu packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to implement difficult compilation methosds to install `wxmaxima`

It is in [main Ubuntu repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/wxmaxima).

You can install it by :

```
sudo apt-get install wxmaxima libc6 libgcc1 libstdc++6 libwxbase3.0-0 libwxgtk3.0-0 maxima maxima-doc
```

Comment: Thanks, I naively assumed that since the Ubuntu documentation page (link in my post above) does not recommend installing through the repo, WxMaxima was not there. I'll make sure to look for the package next time.

Comment: That article is a very old one. See at the very bottom. It was published in 2010. Wxmaxima may not been in main repo at that time.